# Way to download multiple images in HttpServletResponse Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I must implement download functionality to download multiple images when triggered. So far, I implemented it using a single image. But not for multiple ones. Is there a way to do it?

The image source is from the database with blob conversion to image

Here is the current code

```
public void downloadImages(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        List<ScreenUserEntity> users = repo.findAllByImageIsNotNull();

        byte[] decodedBytes = users.get(0).getImage();
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bis);

        response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "name.jpg");
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");

        File outputfile = new File("name.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(outputfile);
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, count);
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();

    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just used the javafx' `ImageIO.getImageReaders(someStream)`, which gives you an iterator over BufferedImages on the stream. That is, If you don't care pulling in all of javafx. On the sending side you just stuff all the images sequentially in the output stream.

Comment: You don't want to zip and download them as a single file? otherwise, you can adopt this to Spring (as it's still servlet underneath)., https://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/downloading-multiple-files-using-multipart-response/

Comment: Thanks this link https://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/downloading-multiple-files-using-multipart-response/ works